# onClick doesn't work on first click after rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const NavigationButtons = ({onBtnClicked, btnClass, label, route, btnAct}) => {
  return (
    <p
      className={`btn ${btnClass} ${btnAct}`}
      onClick={() => onBtnClicked(route)}>
      {label}
    </p>
  );
};
```

This is my button component, I'm giving it to another component as btns1 props

```
 {!isSigned?btns1:windowPixel?btns1:null}
```

Basically, when isSigned is false, btns1 is rendered. There's really no problem here. When isSigned is true, it checks if windowPixel is true, this is changed to true by App.js as a state by measuring the current window. It works perfectly unless I click the button. Resize the window where windowPixel will be false, then on my first click, it doesn't trigger onClick. After that onClick works again.

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (window.matchMedia(`(max-width: 990px)`).matches) {
    this.resizeWindow(true);
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => this.resizeWindow(window.matchMedia(`(max-width: 990px)`).matches));
}
```

This is what checks the window size for windowPixel. chatScroll, is for the panel that expands when btn1 is clicked, btnAct is just for a css that change the color of the button while the panel is expanded. For now, I've put click(), like a bandaid.

```
resizeWindow = (windowPixel) => {
  const {chatScroll, btn1Act} = initialState;

  if (windowPixel !== this.state.windowPixel) {
    if (windowPixel === false) {
      if (this.state.isSigned) {
        document.getElementById('btn1').click();
        this.setState({chatScroll, btn1Act});
      }
    }
    this.setState({windowPixel});
  }
};
```

Comment: If the window resizing is having a side effect on your code it will help a lot to share that implementation as well

Comment: I have included it. thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

The Reason Is Simple Brother in First Click Your Object or function or variable what ever it is , Just Initialize in first click and when you click second time it will Work as per your code.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I not rerender btns1?

Comment: you can but make it initialize in onload